# how to merge (upsert) data aggregates in chunks?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got raw data that I store in collection `raw` and would like to aggregate it and push the aggregated data into a `agg` collection mimicking the upsert method.

- the data I have is time series data and I group based on the date plus some other parameters
- the aggregation counts occurrences based on grouping
- when merging aggregation data, the counts need to be upserted (sum of counts per object)
- when an aggregation happens the raw data is deleted

Is there a functionality that would allow this either through the aggregation pipeline or mapReduce?

I've been looking for this kind of use, but most information I've found regarding merging data is geared towards doing RDBMS style joins.

Comment: Did you look at [$out](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) but you cannot delete from aggregation pipeline.

Comment: I am using `$out`, however it will create the collection or replace the content. It does not do the equivalent of upsert

Comment: I don't think there are other options. You can create js mongo scripts to do this  and run with periodically using a cron.